# mysql optimize group by having count

Tags: mysql, optimization, group-by, count

I have 2 mysql table:

table t1:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `t1` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `type` (`type`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

table t2

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `owa_request` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `date` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `d_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `u_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `browser` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `d_id` (`d_id`),
  KEY `u_id` (`u_id`),
  KEY `date` (`date`),
  KEY `ip` (`ip_address`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Now I want to make such a query:

```
select 
t1.id,t1.url,t1.type,
t2.d_id,t2.date,t2.ip 
from t1,t2 
where t1.id=t2.d_id and t1.type='article' 
group by t2.ip 
HAVING COUNT(t2.ip)>10
```

get all the data group by `t2.ip` and each `t2.ip` should have at least 10 results.

But the query is very slow, 300k rows data (70MB), cost `12.5290 sec`, have I make bad indexes? how to optimize let query under half second? Thanks.

Comment: You have a `KEY type (page_type)` but no `page_type` column. Can you correct the typo?

Comment: Yes your DDL is wrong ! That is bad.

Comment: I would try adding an index on `(ip, d_id)`

Comment: @ypercube, `page_type` should be `type` some writing mistake. I have added an index on `(ip, d_id)` but `Query took 2.5442 sec`, slower than Up_One's answer.

Comment: Have you tried with `SELECT t2.ip FROM ...` only? The other columns you have currently included in the select list will give you arbitary, indeterminate results because of the `group by`.

Comment: @ypercube, `SELECT ip FROM t2 group by t2 HAVING COUNT(ip) >10` Query took 0.0120 sec.

Comment: And how long does it take to run?: `SELECT t2.ip FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON 1.id=t2.d_id WHERE t1.type='article' 
GROUP BY t2.ip 
HAVING COUNT(*)>10;`

Comment: @ypercube, this query cost 0.4596 sec. what can you see on it?

Answer (score 2):

I think that your `type key` is the main problem for you ! as you have it set to the max index size in mysql ! 
 Try to see the real need of those `255(767 byte index)` that is big for a table with that many rows. 
 And check the distinct values in this column '`type`' maybe a partition can be used in order to get rid of unnecessary reads.

Comment: thx, now i use `type` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL, cost 1.5050 sec, but still feel slow, 2 tables only with `70MB`... I have another innodb table, `9.3GB` some query only cost 0.4245 sec.

Comment: Can you run this queries  and post the output ? 1-select max(LENGTH(Marks)) as length from t1; 2- select count(DISTINCT(Marks)) from t1;

Comment: `select max(LENGTH(type)) as length from t1`, 79; `select count(DISTINCT(type)) from t1`, 14. Thanks.

Comment: ok! now alter your table definition by making your type column to "varchar(80) not null" and create 14 partitions representing those 14 distinct type values ! make this on a diferent replicated table - for test only